# How to detect mouseclick outside user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I have modified a drop down control, and replaced combobox dropdown with datagridview. I want to close datagridview, but if I clicked outside datagridview it may be other control or blank form.

I have tried control leave event but it is only working when I clicked on other textbox or focus-able control.

Comment: Look up the Win32 concept of `Capture` (using `SetCapture` and `ReleaseCapture`).

Comment: UI Controls expose the `Capture` property (no need to PInvoke). When set to `true`, mouse events are notified even when generated outside a Control's bounds. You can subscribe to, for example, the the DGV's `VisibleChanged` event and set `dataGridView1.Capture = dataGridView1.Visible`. If `.Visible = true` add a handler to `MouseLeave`, which, when triggered, unsubscribes itself and sets `.Capture = true;`. In the `MouseDown` event, you can have something like: `if (!dataGridView1.ClientRectangle.Contains(e.Location)) { dataGridView1.Visible = false; }`. It will also release the Capture.

Comment: @Jimi I did not get " If .Visible = true add a handler to MouseLeave, which, when triggered, unsubscribes itself and sets .Capture = true;" in which event I have to use it

Comment: If you set `.Visible = true` to show your DGV, then in the `VisibleChanged` event. Use a typed event handler for the `MouseLeave` event , don't use a Lambda and don't subscribe to it in the Designer. So, in `VisibleChanged` you can have: `dataGridView1.Capture = dataGridView1.Visible; if (dataGridView1.Visible) { dataGridView1.MouseLeave += dataGridView1_MouseLeave; }` and in the `MouseLeave` handler: `dataGridView1.MouseLeave -= dataGridView1_MouseLeave; dataGridView1.Capture = true;`.

Comment: You can also handle the `Leave` event, if you want to hide the DGV as soon as a User tabs out of it. Same logic: `private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) { dataGridView1.MouseLeave -= dataGridView1_MouseLeave; dataGridView1.Visible = false; }`. You can subscribe to this event in the Designer.

Comment: thank you so much @Jimi mouse-click captured successfully. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Low-Level Mouse Hook to catch Mouse clicks outside of you app.

Here is a library that will help you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library or https://github.com/charygao/MouseKeyboardLibrary (They are the same)

Example Code (make sure you include the `GlobalHook.cs` and `MouseHook.cs`):

```cs
using MouseKeyboardLibrary;

//....
//...

MouseHook mHook = new MouseHook();

public void Form1_Show()
{
    mHook.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(SomeMethod);
    mHook.Start();
}

public void SomeMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in .Net Framework 4.5, because it uses Win32 API Methods

Comment: When i tried this i also had trouble at first. If you want extra help you can contact me

Comment: And make sure you have System.Windows.Forms added as assembly